# jQuery multiple drop down forms

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form that displays product options from a dropdown.  Within that form data is another dropdown that when selected will show an additional field.  If tank 1 is selected, the option to show the textarea works, however in tank 2 and 3, the textarea dropdown does not work.

```
<select id="tank-select">
  <option>Select One</option>
  <option value="tank-1">Tank1</option>
  <option value="tank-2">Tank2</option>
  <option value="tank-3">Tank3</option>
</select>

<div id="tank-1" class="tank">
  <h3>Tank 1</h3>
  <div class="option1">
    <select>
    <option value="no">No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="option2">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tank-2" class="tank">
  <h3>Tank 2</h3>
  <div class="option1">
    <select>
      <option value="no">No</option>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="option2">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tank-3" class="tank">
  <h3>Tank 3</h3>
  <div class="option1">
    <select>
      <option value="no">No</option>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="option2">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Tank select function for product page
  $("#tank-select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".tank").not("#" + optionValue).hide();
        $("#" + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".tank").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();

  // Tank addon function to show/hide bung fitting locations
  $(".option2").css("display", "none");
  $(".option1 select").change(function() {
    if ($('.option1 select').val() == "yes") {
      $(".option2").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
    } else {
      $(".option2").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
      $('.option2 textarea').val('');
    }
  })
});
```

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLm0jnru/) of this also for testing.

Comment: Not really sure why my question was being downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got this working for anyone else who need something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Tank select function for product page
  $("#tank-select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".tank").not("#" + optionValue).hide();
        $("#" + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".tank").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();

  $(".option2").hide();
    $('.option1 select').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('.tank').find('.option2').toggle((this.value == 'yes'));
    });
});
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLm0jnru/1/)